# Event that triggers once an element is made visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootbox

I have multiple bootbox dialog boxes in my project and I want all of them to appear at the center of the screen, I cannot individually go and calculate the height of each box and position it at the center when the modal shows. Is there a common way to do this. Is there a way to trigger an event when the bootbox is made visible, I tried 'DOMNodeInserted', but this gives recursive error also tried livequery but this did not work. Can anyone tell me how to trigger an event when a dialog box is made visible at a common point.

```
jQuery(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
        if(jQuery(e.target).hasClass('modal')) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                if(jQuery(e.target).height()/2 > 1){
                    var topPos = ((jQuery(window).height() - 30)/2) - jQuery(e.target).find('.modal-dialog').height()/2;
                    jQuery('.modal-content').css('top', topPos);
                }
            },200);
        }
});
```

Regards,

Neha

Comment: Please provide a code example of what have you tried

Comment: I have tried the above code, this brings the popups at the center but it gives 'too much recursion' error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this code**

```
.on("shown.bs.modal", function(e) {
   alert("bootbox is visible");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vxy4t0r2/1/)

**updated**

align bootbox at center

```
.on("shown.bs.modal", function(e) {
$('.modal-content').css({
    'transition':'margin-top 1s linear',
  'margin-top': function (){
        var w = $( window ).height();
        var b = $(".modal-dialog").height();
        var h = (w-b)/2;
        return h+"px";
    }
  });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vxy4t0r2/4/)

Comment: Thank you very much, this works fine. But there is one problem, this code is executed only after the box is visible and it jumps to the center which looks very odd. Is there any solution for this. I tried $(this).animate({'top': '-=30px'},'slow'); too but this does not work properly.

Comment: The same problem is with this demo. The box just jumps to the center.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this sudden jump.

Comment: Thank you, just wanted to ask if the transition can be made smoother.